# Duplicate Target for iPad, but iPad still running iPhone target

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm using Xcode 4 and have a already finished iphone project,
I selected 'Duplicate Target' and chose to let Xcode create my duplicates for iPad,
that worked fine and i have another group with the iPad nibs,

but I guess the target is not getting built by Xcode since the simulator always
starts the iPhone version.
What do I have to do to get the iPad nibs showing?
(application-iPad targets settings are already set to use MainWindow-iPad)

Comment: I just found the options dialog for my Build schemes,
I did not set the iPad Target to build, that was the fault

-> go to Edit, Edit Scheme...

Comment: Please enter this as an answer and accept it.  It is OK to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the options dialog for my Build schemes, 
I did not set the iPad Target to build, that was the fault

go to Edit -> Edit Schemes and set the iPad target to build